# Realm.close() is needed for Android minSdkVersion >= 19?

Tags: java, android, realm

I found in Doc's of Realm for Java https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances that, If you have the luck to work on an app with minSdkVersion >= 19 and Java >= 7 then you can use try-with-resources:

```
try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
// No need to close the Realm instance manually
}
```

I want to know for minSdkVersion >= 19 realm.close() is needed? or just for thread and looping no need no close Realm instance manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say that instead of this construct:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
        // ... Use the Realm instance ...
    } finally {
        realm.close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can do this construct instead (API 19+)

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
       // ... Use the Realm instance ...
    }
    return null;
}
```

And they are equivalent.

---

It does not say that you don't actually need to close local Realm instances, just that if you are using it on background thread, you can leverage the fact that Realm `implements Closable`, therefore `try with resources` automatically calls `realm.close()` in `finally`.

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce you say this is possible just for realm implements Closable? and in API 19+ the closable object has closed at the end of try?

Comment: Realm implements Closable, so if can be used with `try-with-resources`. As such, Realm is auto-closed in what is technically a Finally block at the end of `try(...) { ... }`.